# Is there a term for the useful components of an animal?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

When talking about the "rewards" of killing an animal or beast, what term would be more applicable to refer to the meat, hide, bones, etc.?

In games and other media, the term "loot" is used, but seems too informal or savage for my purposes, which is a formal bestiary for a project.

An example for the use of this phrase or word would be "The ______ of this creature include the shell, teeth, and blood."

Either single words or phrases are applicable.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence where the word would be used, as required by the 'single-word-request' tag.

Comment: Everything but the squeal.

Comment: Resolved, @Spagirl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Harvest" describes both the gathering of living things and the things gathered.  (E.g. Doctors harvest donated hearts. Farmers harvest wheat. The wheat harvest is processed into flour.) That is probably your best single word answer.

[Merriam-Webster: harvest](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harvest)

"Take" can be similarly applied. (e.g. Your take is $5. You take the cake.) "Haul" might also apply in cases with a big load. "Catch" is generally reserved for living creatures taken whole and not their bits.

(I had written up a long bit about how to construct a phrase that indicates which parts are valued by whom, but brevity seemed more valuable. Still, "collected bits" and "valued members" are permutations too fun to forsake.)

Comment: I am quite the fan of "Valued Members," and it's connotation for a hunter's purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider **bounty**.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bounty

> 3. yield, especially of a crop

Its synonymous connotations of "prize," "reward," and "yield" indicate that it represents the portion of something that is useful and desired, as distinguished from "by-products."

The only caveat is that it can apply to entities other than animals.